# Coding for a SharePoint site at the application level

Tags: 2007, development

I have a logging module in my solution that adds log entries to a List<>. I’d like to set up a timer that calls a “WriteEntriesToLogFile” method which writes the entries in the List<> to a file on the disk.

Where would be the best place to add this code so whatever page the user is on the method is called at the specified time intervals? Would the global.asax be the right choice? I’m a bit worried that would affect other SharePoint web sites on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve gone in a slightly different direct and added a timer to the constructor of the Logging class. Something along these lines...

```
Timer LogTimer = new Timer();
LogTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WriteLogEntriesToDisk);
LogTimer.Interval = 5000;
LogTimer.Start();
```

I’m interested to know what people think, is this a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider an HTTP module. This should give you the universal behavior your are looking for. However, this is handling individual requests and not doing anything on a timed basis. Look at a custom timer job if it needs to be on a schedule.

Comment: Agreed- custom timer job deployed via a Feature, so you can enable/disable from Site Settings/Site Features page (if you wanted to).